# C# SimpleJson with Json returned by Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, simplejson

I have a Asp.Net Core 2.1 API that returns from a class called DataSet.  What can I do to get SimpleJson to decode the json data.  Thank you.

```
var response = restClient.Execute(request);
var ret = response.Content;
DataSet mydata = SimpleJson.SimpleJson.Deserialize<DataSet>(ret);
```

The mydata is always null.

```
// This is json data returned by server    
    {"prime":"Af//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////",
        "a":"Af/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8",
        "b":"AFGVPrlhjhyaH5KaIaC2hUDuotpyW5mzFfO4tImRjvEJ4VYZOVHsfpN7FlLAvTuxvwc1c9+IPSw08e9FH9RrUD8A"}

public class DataSet
{
    public byte[] prime {get;set;}
    public byte[] a {get;set;}
    public byte[] b {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: could you please add content in `response.Content`?

Comment: There is no error, just empty/null mydata.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use newtonsoft Json framework.
It is awesome https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

And here are the serialization samples: 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

Comment: Newtonsoft Json framework has no problem but it is obese :).

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft JSON, you can do the following quite easily:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var jsonString = @"{'prime':'Af//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////',
        'a':'Af/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8',
        'b':'AFGVPrlhjhyaH5KaIaC2hUDuotpyW5mzFfO4tImRjvEJ4VYZOVHsfpN7FlLAvTuxvwc1c9+IPSw08e9FH9RrUD8A'}";

        var dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonString);

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataSet.prime));
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataSet.a));
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataSet.b));
    }
}

public class DataSet
{
    public byte[] prime {get;set;}
    public byte[] a {get;set;}
    public byte[] b {get;set;}
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to encode, but I've guessed it was something in UTF-8?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/g4pBWc

Comment: Just as I mentioned above, Newtonsoft framework has no problem deserializing it. Basically the data is from BigInteger.   BigInteger big = new BigInteger(); mydata.Prime = big.ToByteArray();